# jQuery disable click function when value gets to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator, increment, decrement

I've been trying many different methods and rewriting my code to achieve something that I feel is quite simple but I can't seem to get it.

I have two increment/decrement `button`s but I want to disable the `click` function on the subtract `button` when the value reaches `0` as to not input negative numbers.

Currently on my jsfiddle I have the calculator working, however when I try to disable the subtract `button` when the value is `0`, it disables the `button` completely, even when the value is no longer `0`. It seems jQuery is not checking to see if the value has changed.

Any ideas on how can I fix this? Thanks!

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jony000/frupofqe/22/

```
<p align="center">
How often do you shower?
</p>
<table class="shower">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="rate-minus">
                -
            </td>
            <td class="shower-rate">0</td>
            <td class="rate-plus">
                +
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p align="center">
  Times a Day
</p>
```

JQuery

```
var showers = 0;
var plus = $(".rate-plus");
var minus = $(".rate-minus");
var rate = $(".shower-rate");

plus.click(function() {
    showers++;
    rate.html(showers);
})

minus.click(function() {
    showers--;
    rate.html(showers);
})

/*if (showers == 0) {
    minus.css("pointer-events","none");
    } else{
    minus.css("pointer-events", "auto");
}*/
```

Comment: Why not just not decrement below 0?  Seems round-about to disable the control, then you have to check it anytime the value changes to see if its above 0 again.  Seems too complicated for something that can easily be handled in the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set up an call that would check a given condition (if your value is 0) and use that to toggle if your subtract button was enabled or disabled via a ternary operation :

```
minus.css("pointer-events",showers === 0 ? "none" : "auto");
```

Then you could simply check for that scenario when either of your events occur :

```
plus.click(function(){
   showers++;
   UpdateRate();
})

minus.click(function(){
   showers--;
   UpdateRate();
})

function UpdateRate() {
   // This will disable your button if showers is 0
   minus.css("pointer-events",showers === 0 ? "none" : "auto");
   rate.html(showers);
}
```

**Example**

[image]

```js
    var rateMinus = $(".rate-minus");
    var ratePlus = $(".rate-plus");
    var rate = $(".shower-rate");
    var value = 0;


    ratePlus.click(function() {
      value++;
      UpdateRate();
    })

     rateMinus.click(function() {
      value--;
      UpdateRate();
    })

    function UpdateRate() {
      debugger;
      // This will disable your button if showers is 0
      rateMinus.css("pointer-events", value === 0 ? "none" : "auto");
      rate.html(value);
    }
```

```css
table {
  margin: auto;
  color: #cecece;
}
.shower td {
  padding: 10px;
}
.rate-minus,
.rate-plus,
.period-minus,
.period-plus {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #a8d6ff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
How often do you shower?
<table class="shower">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rate-minus" id="test">
        -
      </td>
      <td class="shower-rate">0</td>
      <td class="rate-plus">
        +
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>

<p align="center">
  Times a
</p>
<table class="shower">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="period-minus">
        -
      </td>
      <td class="shower-period">
        Day
      </td>
      <td class="period-plus">
        +
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if `shower` is zero inside the `click` event listener for the `minus` element:

```
minus.click(function() {
  rate.html(--showers);
  if (showers === 0) {
    minus.css("pointer-events", "none");
  } else{
    minus.css("pointer-events", "auto");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for 0 before you decrement.  I believe its more clearly readable to just not decrement it rather than disabling the control, unless you had other logic thats not shown in the demo.

```js
var showers = 0;
var plus = $(".rate-plus");
var minus = $(".rate-minus");
var rate = $(".shower-rate");

plus.click(function(){
  showers++;
  rate.html(showers);
})

minus.click(function(){
  if (showers <= 0)
      return;
  showers--;
  rate.html(showers);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p align="center">
How often do you shower?
</p>
<table class="shower">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="rate-minus">
                -
            </td>
            <td class="shower-rate">0</td>
            <td class="rate-plus">
                +
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p align="center">
  Times a Day
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to move your entire `if` block at the bottom inside of your functions... or better yet, create a new function and call that one inside the others. Here's an example

```
var showers = 0;
var plus = $(".rate-plus");
var minus = $(".rate-minus");
var rate = $(".shower-rate");

//This is new
var checkForZero = function() {
    if (showers == 0) {
        minus.css("pointer-events","none");
    } else {
        minus.css("pointer-events", "auto");
    }
};

plus.click(function(){
showers++;
rate.html(showers);
checkForZero(); //call new function
})

minus.click(function(){
showers--;
rate.html(showers);
checkForZero(); //call new function
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
var rateMinus = $(".rate-minus");

var value = 0;
updateRateMinus(); // update on initial load

$(".rate-plus").click(function() {
  parseInt($(".shower-rate").text(value + 1));
  value = value + 1;
  updateRateMinus();
});
$(".rate-minus").click(function() {
  parseInt($(".shower-rate").text(value - 1));
  value = value - 1;
  updateRateMinus();

});

function updateRateMinus() {
  if ($(".shower-rate").text() == 0) {
    rateMinus.css('pointer-events', 'none');
  } else {
    rateMinus.css("pointer-events", "auto");
  }

}
```